# Route can't be identified in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a dynamic navigation (all names, icons, links, aand all other things comes from table).
But when I tried to use link I get error that `Route [soon] not defined`

```
                @foreach($categories as $item)
                    <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
                        <a class="fw-bold" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="uil {{ $item->icon }} me-2 d-inline-block"></i>{{ $item->title }}</a>
                        <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                            @foreach($item['children'] as $child)
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="{{ route($child->link)}}">{{ $child->title }}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
```

web route code:

```
Route::prefix(config('admintw.prefix'))->middleware(['auth', 
'verified', 'activeUser', 'IpCheckMiddleware'])->group(function () {
     Route::get('soon', \App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Miscellaneous\Comingsoon::class)->name('soon');
});
```

In the table's link column there is "soon".

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` and see if your route is actually listed ... perhaps you cached your routes for some odd reason

Comment: Maybe you don't have named routes for your $child variable so it could be better to user url($child->link) instead of route()

Comment: @lagbox yeah, it is listed

Comment: and that is the full name of the route? unless there is some weird character encoding happening there the route should exist (be defined) if that is its name

Comment: What is the output of @dd($child->link) ? And could you share your php artisan route:list ?

Comment: the path doesn't matter, as long as the name is actually `soon` it would not be undefined (since you are using the `route` helper, which uses names)

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan tinker` and check `route('soon')` and if you get an error, that means that route

```
'verified', 'activeUser', 'IpCheckMiddleware'])->group(function () {
     Route::get('soon', \App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Miscellaneous\Comingsoon::class)->name('soon');
});
```

wasn't processed

try with something simple like

```
Route::get('soon', \App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Miscellaneous\Comingsoon::class)->name('soon');
```